# Line Break when copying Data from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a huge script that returns a lot of data, the returned number of rows are over 50K.

The issue I am having is that when I copy and paste it into a Excel, randomly there are break lines, where columns are broken into multiple rows. Please see example below, how can I make it so the rows don't break?

I am using SQL Server 2014 and the results are same when I do save data as CSV file or copy paste, both of them have same issues.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste from where? SSMS? Do you have line breaks in the data?

Comment: Try using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard - in SSMS right click the database, and then Tasks, Export Data.

Comment: Not sure about the exact problem but some questions that might help you dig into it: 1) How are you originally querying the DB / with what query tool? 2) Does the data in the DB have carriage returns, tabs, or special characters in it and are those characters where this is breaking? 3) Can you hook Excel up to your DB and query directly into your spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi @Ben for hooking up the Database to Excel, do I need to take my scrip turn it into a Store Proc and then run it?

Comment: @Ahmad I haven't done it in a long time but Excel used to include a tool called (I think) Microsoft Query. You could pretty easily just copy an SQL statement into it and then run the statement. Here is a link to the current approach for this: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-query-an-external-database-in-excel/ I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments, I was able to use SQL server Import and Export Wizard as told by @RodneyEllis and it actually didnt break lines. Thanks again!